# Android, ProGuard, and keepclasseswithmembernames

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, minimization

A common pattern in ProGuard configs for Android applications is to preserve custom `View` classes, since they are probably referenced only from layout XML instead of application code.

Upon project creation, the ADT therefore add these rules to a project's proguard.cfg:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
```

I guess the idea here is to say that whenever a class defines a constructor that may be called by a layout inflater, then preserve it. However, according to the ProGuard docs, the `keepclasseswithmembernames` qualifier is shorthand for `keepclasseswithmembers` and `allowshrinking`, which if I understand correctly means: it's allowed to remove these classes, but if they're kept, don't obfuscate its member names (probably to not break bindings between XML attribute names and class setters).

But doesn't that mean that those classes will still be removed during the shrinking phase (allowshrinking = true), unless they are referenced directly in code? Indeed that is what happened with a custom widget we're using in our app, and I could fix the issue by setting the rule to just `keepclasseswithmembers` since that will simply preserve the matching classes entirely (it's worth noting that this is what the official [ProGuard Android example](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication) does, too).

Am I misreading the ProGuard docs or is this a bug in the ADT project wizard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration in the Android SDK (at least up to version 11) is not entirely correct, indeed.

The [configuration for Android](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication) in the ProGuard documentation correctly specifies "-keepclasseswithmembers", not "-keepclasseswithmembernames".

Comment: Thanks, I've raised an issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16384

Comment: Thanks for this remark, saved me a lot of time. However, first time for me to configure Proguard, too bad there is no automatic configuration by going through the project content.

Answer (score 0):

When I first tried the integrated proguard with Ant, my app kept crashing with runtime errors on the clickhandlers. (I always set these in XML). I assumed I must be doing something wrong, couldn't work out what, so added the line

```
-dontshrink
```

at the top of the proguard.cfg.

Maybe this isn't optimal but it stopped the run time errors!

*Addendum*

In fact I checked this by looking at usage.txt. The clickhandlers were listed in there before I added the dontshrink option, after I added it, usage.txt was empty as would be expected.

Comment: Hey Nick, that's exactly what I suspected, too. The problem is that click handlers in XML are translated to method invocations via reflection, but if ProGuard obfuscates method names, then this of course breaks. The `dontshrink` option would of course fix this, but it's a bit of a sledgehammer, since it will apply to all classes.

Comment: Well, it still obfuscates all the  method names that haven't been been excluded by the keepclasseswithmembernames directive including the clickhandler. The problem wasn't the obfuscation, it was that the fact that it removed the method because it wasn't referenced in the code anywhere. So as long as you are prepared to remove any truly unused code yourself, it doesn't seem to be that much of a sledgehammer.

Comment: I use a rule like this to keep XML-defined click handlers:
`-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}` rather than disabling shrinking.