# Constructor not matched for class {proguard]

Tags: android, proguard, simple-framework

I am enabling proguard in my application. Whenever I am building my application I am getting following error.
`Constructor not matched for class com.acs.nomad.d.b.e`

As Per my mapping file the class this is referring to is as below

```
package com.my.package;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root (name = "folders")
public class Folders 
{
    @ElementList (entry = "contactFolder", required = false, inline = true)
    private ArrayList<ContactFolder> contactFolder;
    
    /**
     * List of contact folders
     */
    public ArrayList<ContactFolder> getContactFolder() 
    {
        return contactFolder;
    }

}
```

I have tried all option as per these url
[proguard-obfuscation-is-breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163250/proguard-obfuscation-is-breaking-simplexml)

[proguard-android-and-abstract-class-instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796241/android-proguard-and-keepclasseswithmembernames)

[android-proguard-and-keepclasseswithmembernames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796241/android-proguard-and-keepclasseswithmembernames)

Nothing seems to work. My Proguard.config file is

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes Signature, *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    !private <fields>;
    !private <methods>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keep public class org.simpleframework.**{ *; } 
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.**{ *; } 
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{ *; } 
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.**{ *; }

#Added commands
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
    public static int v(...);
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}

#dont warn for the android support version
-dontwarn android.support.**

# dont warn for google or framework related warning
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.**

#-dontshrink

-keepattributes ElementList, Root

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* *;
}
```

If you notice `-dontshrink` command is commented out. I want to shrink the apk so I don't want to run that command. Please also note that I am uncommenting `-dontshrink` command, it works.
Can anybody tell whats wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution? I am facing similar problem.